# Resize table with rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem arises when using [this script](http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables) with not standard tables that use rowspan.

Look second table on resize.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbq0q0jf/)

```html
<table class="table2 responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">name</th>
      <th colspan="3">1</th>
      <th rowspan="2">5</th>
      <th colspan="2">6</th>
      <th rowspan="2">9</th>
      <th rowspan="2">10</th>
      <th rowspan="2">11</th>
      <th rowspan="2">12</th>
      <th rowspan="2">13</th>
      <th rowspan="2">14</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: 'The problem arises...' - please describe the problem, we shouldn't have to guess which of your expectations are not being met, our effort should be going into finding you a solution

Comment: @AndrasZoltan on resize. Says in the second sentence. Look at the fiddle and resize it.

Comment: What does the script do? Why don't you use only css to manage the responsive?

Answer (score 0):

```
copy.find("td:not(:first-child), th:not(:first-child)").css("display", "none");
```

it jumps over the cell so it is not hidden and the hidden is not shown.
For test you can manually add `display:none` and remove `display:none` it should work like you want.